# MouseInputAdapter on JMenuBar - not all methods get called

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have a `JComponent` with `JMenuBar` in it. I would like to be able to drag the component by clicking on it and dragging the mouse to the desired location. I have already implemented this functionality by adding the `MouseInputAdapter` methods to its `Border` and it works great.

However, I would like to apply the same functionality on the `JMenuBar`, the `mouseDragged()` method does not get called.

Here is the menu listener (stripped version for testing):

```
menuBar.addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter() {

            private Point startPos = null;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

                startPos = me.getPoint();
                // works fine
                System.out.println("startPos: " + startPos.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                // this does not get called...
                System.out.println("dragging.............");
            }

 });
```

I dont think that this is the problem, but here is the Listener used for the whole component. Could these two listeners somehow collide? I tried removingthis listener but it did not solve anything:

```
// this works with the border
this.addMouseListener(resizeListener);

MouseInputListener resizeListener = new MouseInputAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
            // put this widget on top when mouse moves across it
            putOnTop();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
            // put this widget on top when mouse moves across it
            putOnTop();
            WidgetBorder border = (WidgetBorder) getBorder();
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(border.getResizeCursor(me)));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        }

        private int cursor;
        private Point startPos = null;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

            WidgetBorder border = (WidgetBorder) getBorder();
            cursor = border.getResizeCursor(me);

            startPos = me.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            if (startPos != null) {

                // widget cant be resized under its minimum size
                if (widget.getWidth() < WidgetConstants.MIN_WIDTH) {
                    widget.setBounds(widget.getX(), widget.getY(), WidgetConstants.MIN_WIDTH + 1, widget.getHeight());
                    return;
                }
                if (widget.getHeight() < WidgetConstants.MIN_HEIGHT) {
                    widget.setBounds(widget.getX(), widget.getY(), widget.getWidth(), WidgetConstants.MIN_HEIGHT + 1);
                    return;
                }

                int dx = me.getX() - startPos.x;
                int dy = me.getY() - startPos.y;
                switch (cursor) {
                    case Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                        setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth() + dx, getHeight() + dy);
                        startPos = me.getPoint();
                        repaintParent();
                        break;
                    case Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR:
                        Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
                        bounds.translate(dx, dy);
                        setBounds(bounds);
                        repaintParent();
                }

                // cursor shouldn't change while dragging 
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(cursor));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            startPos = null;
        }
    };
```

What am I missing here? Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MouseInputAdapter` implements many interfaces (e.g. `MouseListener`, `MouseMotionListener` etc.).

You have to add this with multiple methods, e.g. with `Component.addMouseListener()` if you want `mouseClicked()` to be called, `Component.addMouseMotionListener()` if you want `mouseDragged()` to be called and `Component.addWheelListener()` if you want `mouseWheelMoved()` to be called.

You can pass the same reference of course, but you have to add your listener implementation with multiple methods. The reason is because for example `Component.addMouseListener()` expects a `MouseListener` interface, and will only call the methods defined in the `MouseListener` interface, even if you pass an object that implements other methods from other interfaces.

Comment: Thank you, such a fool mistake and one spends half an hour figuring it out xD

Comment: I knew the answer immediately because I've fallen into this pit many times. The fact that an Adapter implements multiple interfaces easily makes you believe that all the implemented interfaces will be registered and work right away if you register it...